# Print all unique elements of pandas Series without truncation

Tags: python, pandas, printing

I have a dataframe and I want to print all unique elements of a column. So I use `df.mycolumn.unique()`, but I get a truncated list:

```
[SCO, ENG, SPA, NED, ..., AUT, FRA, GER]
```

How to print all elements without truncation?

Comment: The moderator seems to believe the link answers this question, which is not correct. Indeed he/she confuses the dataframe display parameters with the unique() method. The question has thus been closed without reason.

Comment: please edit the question to include a minimum example of the code you are having problems with

Comment: Updated the dupe